# Last Year Week to Date Sales DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a measure of Week to date sales and trying to create a measure for last year week to date.

The problem is Week To Date Sales LY is not coming correct. Can anyone help in this regard?

I am using following formula:

```
`Weekly Sales:= 
var CurrentDate=LASTDATE('Date'[Date])
var DayNumberOfWeek=WEEKDAY(LASTDATE('Date'[Date]),3)
return
CALCULATE(
    DetailSales[Sales],
DATESBETWEEN(
    'Date'[Date],
DATEADD(
    CurrentDate,
    -1*DayNumberOfWeek,
    DAY),
    CurrentDate))

Week To Date Sales LY:= CALCULATE([Weekly Sales], ALLSELECTED('Date'),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR() doesn't work on a week-basis. You'll need to create a date table with standard week numbers, day-of-the-week numbers, and the week-year, and then use those columns to identify which is the same period last year. Essentially, we need to recreate our own Calendar with a week-level hierarchy. This means assigning dates to a standard week #, and assigning those weeks to a year (that may not align to a standard calendar year).

```
Day_Of_The_Week = 
VAR return_type = 2 //Week starting Monday
RETURN WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date],return_type )-1

Week_Year = YEAR( 'Calendar'[Date] - 'Calendar'[Day_Of_The_Week] )

Standard_Week_Number = 
VAR return_type = 2 //Week starting Monday
VAR start_of_week = 'Calendar'[Date] - 'Calendar'[Day_Of_The_Week]
VAR start_of_calendar_year = DATE( YEAR( 'Calendar'[BO Week] ), 1, 1 ) 
VAR start_of_first_week_of_year = 
    start_of_calendar_year 
    + MOD( 7 - ( WEEKDAY(start_of_calendar_year ,return_type ) - 1 ), 7 )
RETURN ( start_of_week - start_of_first_week_of_year  ) / 7 + 1
```

Then change your measure to use these:

```
Week To Date Sales LY = 
CALCULATE(
     [Weekly Sales], 
     ALLEXCEPT( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Standard_Week_Number ] ),
     'Calendar'[Week_Year] + 1 IN VALUES( 'Calendar'[Week_Year] )
)
```

This will return the weekly sales for the same standard week number of the prior year. If multiple weeks are selected, it will return the same week numbers of the prior year. If multiple years are selected, the selected years will be shifted back one year.

Comment: Dear Luke, thanks for your detailed response. I have tried the above solution but it is giving following error: "The function expects a table expression for argument '2', but a string or numeric expression was used." Also there is another syntax error: " VALUES( 'dDate'[Week_Year] ) - 1 is not a valid table "

Comment: Apologies for that; I made a tweak to the final measure that should resolve both errors. Let me know how that works.

Answer (score -1):

Update:
I am able to solve the problem by using following without any need of custom table:

```
WTD PY = IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Date[Year] )
    && HASONEVALUE (Date[WeekOfYear] ), CALCULATE(
    [WTD_Sales],
    
        FILTER(ALL(Date),
        Date[Year] = FORMAT(VALUES ( Date[Year] )-1,"")
            && Date[WeekOfYear] = MAX( Date[WeekOfYear] )
            && Date[DayOfWeekNo] = MAX( Date[DayOfWeekNo] )
    )
))
```

Comment: Glad you figured this out. One note, your solution with FILTER(ALL(),...) invokes an extra calculations step of stripping filters and reinstating them vs CALCULATE(..,ALLEXCEPT()) only strips the necessary filters, resulting in a much more efficient query. Additionally, did you end up using my WeekOfYeear expression in your table? If my answer solved your problem, be sure to accept it as the solution rather than reposting essentially the same thing as your own work.